# Checking that the conditions are correct accordingly

Tags: r

I would like to know if the code below is properly written for generating `group_cols`. Making a brief explanation of the code I made:

My first `if()` is if I have any row where `PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week== Wk`. The `else if` is when I have `PV$Week == Wk` and `PV$Category==CategoryChosse`, but not `PV$DTT == DTest`. That's why I inserted the sign `!`. The last condition means if I don't have any of the conditions reported above. Is the code correct according to my thinking?

```
PV <- structure(list(date2 = c("2021-06-23", "2021-06-24"), Week = c("Wednesday", 
 "Thursday"), Category = c("ABC", "FDE"), DTT = c("Hol", "Hol"), DR1 = c(4, 1), 
DR01_PV = c(0, 0), DR02_PV = c(0, -1), DR03_PV = c(-5,-4), DR04_PV = c(-1, -3), 
DR05_PV = c(-1, -3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)

    > PV
           date2      Week Category DTT DR1 DR01_PV DR02_PV DR03_PV DR04_PV DR05_PV
    1 2021-06-23 Wednesday      ABC Hol   4       0       0      -5      -1      -1
    2 2021-06-24  Thursday      FDE Hol   1       0      -1      -4      -3      -3

group_cols <-
  if (any(PV$DTT == DTest & PV$Week == Wk, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    c("Category", "Week", "DTT")
  } else if (any(PV$Week == Wk & PV$Category == CategoryChosse & !PV$DTT == DTest, na.rm=TRUE)) {
    c("Category", "Week")
  } else {
    "Week"
  }
```

**Running some tests:**

```
1)
CategoryChosse<-"FDE"
DTest<-"0"
Wk<-"Thursday"

> group_cols
[1] "Category" "Week"

2)
CategoryChosse<-"FDE"
DTest<-"Hol"
Wk<-"Thursday"

[1] "Category" "Week" "DTT"

3)
CategoryChosse<-"FDE"
DTest<-"Hol"
Wk<-"Friday"

> group_cols
[1] "Week"
```

Comment: Isn't reproducible, a closing bracket is missing though.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I had forgotten to insert in some input data to test. But, the main idea is to know if what I wrote in the question matches the code I made. What do you think?

Comment: Use `!=` as "not equal"

Comment: To change this: `!PV$DTT == DTest` ?So how does it look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the code matches what you are saying it should do in your question. Two suggestions:

1. Use `PV$DTT != DTest` instead of `!PV$DTT == DTest` for better clarity.
2. It is actually unnecessary (but not harmful) to include the condition `PV$DTT != DTest` in the second `if`. Whenever the second `if` is reached, it means that either `PV$DTT == DTest` is false or `PV$Week == Wk` is false. Since the second `if` checks for `PV$Week == Wk` being true, checking `PV$DTT != DTest` becomes redundant.